# Production and Development Certifcate Option is disable

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, app-store

My client give me his apple account.In which option for creating certificate is disabled. 
   I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444086/app-store-and-ad-hoc-disabled) . But i could not find any official document. Currently there are
   five distribution certificate.

I want to create a new production certificate .How it can be enabled.

NOTE : I know i can export p12 file from previous certificate but it is not available.

Is there any other way?

EDIT
[I have gone though it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230736/create-ios-in-house-and-ad-hoc-certificate-option-disabled) I have admin credentials..
   [image]

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230736/create-ios-in-house-and-ad-hoc-certificate-option-disabled

Comment: @VishwaPatel I have admin account credentials....