# iOS Enterprise Distribution Cert

Tags: ios, in-house-distribution

The way I understand it that in Enterprise case you can only have 1 cert for **In-House and Ad Hoc** distribution( from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17230736/create-ios-in-house-and-ad-hoc-certificate-option-disabled)). But when I check my client Company Enterprise Account, they have 2 **iOS Distribution** certs.

1. Why is this possible? One possible scenario I can think of is that it is for other type of distribution rather than **In-House and Ad Hoc**.
2. If ever I want to add another cert for **In-House and Ad Hoc**, is it possible and how to do that?
3. What if I delete my current **In-House and Ad Hoc** cert? Will it affect my current enterprise app?

Answer (score 1):

> Why is this possible? One possible scenario I can think of is that it
>   is for other type of distribution rather than In-House and Ad Hoc.

It's relatively new that you can have multiple distribution certificates, maybe in the last year.

> If ever I want to add another cert for In-House and Ad Hoc, is it
>   possible and how to do that?

Log on to your account, go to Certificates and press the + button in the top right, select Distribution for the certification type.

> What if I delete my current In-House and Ad Hoc cert? Will it affect
>   my current enterprise app?

Yes, it will affect your current app.  It will no longer open on devices.  You will need to release an updated app built with a new/edited provisioning profile that references your new certificate.

Comment: For 2 apparently it is not possible. I tried. the **In-House and Ad Hoc** button is gray-out.

Comment: Not sure, I just did it on mine.  I don't know why yours would be greyed out.